# How to include a text role like math as field name in a field list in restructured text?

Tags: restructuredtext

I have a [field list](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#field-lists) in restructed text. It goes like:

```
:fieldA:
:fieldB:
```

and prints a list of field names followed by colons a.

I want to have some math in my field names. Therefore I want to use the [math text role](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html):

```
:math:'\alpha'
```

which prints and alpha symbol. However, putting this as a field name of a field list like:

```
:fieldA:
:fieldB:
::math:'\alpha':
```

produces a warning (field list ends without a blank line) and puts the alpha surrounded by colons on the start of the next line.

It doesn't seem to work, the colons to mark the text roles and the colons to mark the field names may not be used in a nested fashion. Is this true or is there a way to achieve symbols, subscripts, superscripts, ... as field names in field lists?

I use Sphinx 1.4 to convert restructured text to HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
:fieldA:
:fieldB:
:|fieldMath|:

.. |fieldMath| replace:: :math:`α_t(i) = P(λ)`
```

Comment: Nice, it works. The only drawback is a bit of meaningless repetitions.